# How add a link to a pseudo element in jQuery without modifying HTML? - Updated > Functions.php

Tags: php, jquery, css, wordpress, function

I'm trying to assign a url to a pseudo element (`button`) next to the `h1`. I'm working on a specific WordPress page that I cannot modify because the `h1` is the `entry-title`.

The problem is I cannot use `h1.entry-title::after` to assign a link. Can someone help me please?

```js
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

$j(document).ready(function() {
  $j("h1.entry-title::after").click(function() {
    window.open('http://www.google.com/');
  });
});
```

```css
#pageid1 h1.entry-title::after {
  content: 'contact Yes Link';
  right: 80px;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
  -moz-border-radius: 20px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: 600;
  padding: 0px 13px;
  background-color: #95c11e;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 17px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .23);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 10px 10px 17px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .23);
  -moz-box-shadow: 10px 10px 17px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .23);
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="pageid1">
  <h1 class="entry-title"> Title Page - No Link </h1>
</div>
```

Comment: you cannot assign a link to a pseudo element. Pseudo element cannot be transformed to links and they cannot have event listener

Comment: if you are able to add a wordpress `action` then simply add a *real* link inside the `h1`

Comment: I tried this but it doesnt work, anyway Im not a php developer and the dev. of customizr theme doesnt answer to my question.

```add_action ('__before_archive_title', 'button_beside_title');

function button_beside_title() {
if ( !is_page( array( '3154' ) ) ){
    echo 'Text Example';
}}```

Comment: add the wordpress and php tag if you want to get help or ask in the wordpress stackexchange ... actually your question will not get any solution using CSS/jQuery. It will soon get closed as a duplicate

Comment: Thank you Temani, I dont want link H1 but the button only and I made this action  
```  add_action ('__before_archive_title', 'button_link');

function button_link ( $link ) {
if ( !is_page( '3154' ) ) {
 $link = 'http://www.website.com';
}}  ```  The mouse arrow see the link but the url doesn't work. What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript to get pseudo content and append a link to H1.

Here is the CSS code:

```
/* Add pseudo at first */
#pageid1 h1.entry-title::after {
   content: 'contact Yes Link';
   right: 80px;
   position: absolute;
   -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
   -moz-border-radius: 20px;
   border-radius: 20px;
   color: #fff;
   font-size: 28px;
   font-weight: 600;
   padding: 0px 13px;
   background-color: #95c11e;
   box-shadow: 10px 10px 17px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .23);
   -webkit-box-shadow: 10px 10px 17px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .23);
   -moz-box-shadow: 10px 10px 17px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .23);
   text-decoration: none;
   display: inline-block;
   cursor: pointer;
}

/* Remove pseudo */
#pageid1 h1.entry-title.pseudoed::after {
   display: none;
}

/* Style your link like pseudo */
#pageid1 h1.entry-title .my-pseudo-link {
   right: 80px;
   position: absolute;
   -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
   -moz-border-radius: 20px;
   border-radius: 20px;
   color: #fff;
   font-size: 28px;
   font-weight: 600;
   padding: 0px 13px;
   background-color: #95c11e;
   box-shadow: 10px 10px 17px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .23);
   -webkit-box-shadow: 10px 10px 17px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .23);
   -moz-box-shadow: 10px 10px 17px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .23);
   text-decoration: none;
   display: inline-block;
   cursor: pointer;
}
```

And here is the JS/jQuery code:

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

$j(document).ready(function() {
   var pseudoLink = $j('<a href="https://google.com"></a>').html(window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('#pageid1 h1.entry-title'), ':after').getPropertyValue('content'));
   $j('#pageid1 h1.entry-title').addClass('pseudoed').append(pseudoContent);
});
```